# How can I manage form validity from an Angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have error spans on a page:

```
<span id="example" name="example" ng-model="example">
    <span ng-show="form.example.$error.exampleError">
        {{'example' | translate}} 
    </span>
</span>
```

I need to set the validity on this from a directive so I am passing the form as an attribute.

```
<form name="form">
    <my-directive form="form"></my-directive>
</form>
```

Inside the directive I then set the validity to true or false.

This works, however from a design perspective I am creating a circular dependency as I have a directive inside a form and then I am passing the form to the directive, so my question really is, is there a better way to achieve this with passing the form to the directive?

I could create a service that stores the state of the form (true/false) and use ng-show, but I would prefer to use $error and $setValidity.

Answer (score 1):

This article really helped me with this kind of scenario:

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/11/exploring-angular-1.3-validators-pipeline.html

```
angular.module("app")
.directive('validateExample', function () {
    return {
        require: 'form',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (you-want-example-to-be-valid) {
                ctrl.$setValidity("example", true);
            }else{
                ctrl.$setValidity("example", false);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Then in your html you would do something like this:

```
<form name="FormName" validate-example novalidate>
    <input id="example" name="example" ng-model="example"/>
</form>
<div ng-messages="FormName.$error" role="alert">
    <div class="alert-danger" ng-message="example">This error will show if example is invalid according to the directive
    </div>
</div>
```

Take note that I'm using Angular's ngMessages you can read more on it here:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your directive does.
Take a look at require property for the directive - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

One way is to use attribute directive on the form itself.

```
angular.module('app').directive('formDirective', function() {
  return {
    require: 'form',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
      //do stuff with your form using formCtrl
    }
  };
});
```

Then you do

```
<form name="form" form-directive>
</form>
```